# Webpack 2 with webpack-dev-middleware: Module not found

Tags: webpack

In my `webpack.config.js` i use `path.resolve` to specify my entry points.
Webpack is able to handle it and build the bundle(s) as expected.

But in my `server.js` i need to load the `webpack.config.js` in order to pass it to the webpack-dev-middleware. At runtime i receive a error

"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve...." with a relative path.

I console logged the config at bundle time (absolute path) and at runtime in my `server.js` (relative path).

Is there a way to handle this? E.g. in the webpack entry points for

```
vendor: [
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  'webpack-hot-middleware/client?http://localhost:3000',
  path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/vendor/', 'index.js')
]
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?